# Multiple ajax calls within ajax call while data is being received

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX/jQuery so please bear with me.....here is a mind-bender ;)

I am making an AJAX call to a php script (process_data.php) which processes a large amount of data and returns THREE flags. Each flag indicates the completion of a process and availability of data for the calling script. My ajax call should do this:

```
Call  process_data.php asynchronously....

process_data.php "echoes" three flags (at approximately 4 second intervals)

Upon echoing of the first flag...make another ajax call to get_first_dataset.php

Upon echoing of second flag...make ajax call to get_second_dataset.php

Upon echoing of third flag...make ajax call to get_third_dataset.php
```

So basically I am asking how to process data returned from an AJAX call in "real time" and how to make another AJAX call within a running ajax call.....again, sorry if I am using "newbish" terminology...

Comment: You can use setInterval(), put your ajax in a function, and call in the interval setInterval(youtAjaxFunction, 1000 // every 1 sec), after the last "echo" you can kill the interval function.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really possible in javascript. (without web sockets at least)

Javascript is going to wait until the entire body is downloaded before completing so it will wait 12 seconds for the PHP file to finish echoing.

So the a solution would be:

Have your PHP return immediately after the first call. Then set up another endpoint Javascript can query at intervals to get the status of flags.

```
Call process_data.php call completes immediately
Call process_data_status.php at 4 second intervals
if process_data_status.php returns flag 1
    make ajax call to get_first_dataset.php
if process_data_status.php returns flag 2
    make ajax call to get_second_dataset.php
if process_data_status.php returns flag 3
    make ajax call to get_third_dataset.php
```

Comment: "This isn't really possible in javascript. (without web sockets at least)"  .....I was thinking something on the lines of 'onprogress" in javascript which processes streaming data?!

Comment: onprogress doesn't give you the response body as it is streaming. Essentially what you want to do is [long polling](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

this is not a big mind-bender... you basicaly have to `link` ajax callbacks one by one.. something alone this lines..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "process_data.php",
    data: { name: 'John', age: 22 },
})
.done(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "process_data.php",
        data: { name: 'John', age: 22 },
    })
    .done(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "process_data.php",
            data: { name: 'John', age: 22 },
        })
        .done(function(){
            console.log('last call done!')
        })
    })
})
```

the main thing is that you have to process data from server and link that to DOM and do manipulation.. and that's it!

Comment: I need to make ajax calls WHILE the first ajax call is receiving data...not after its done getting the data from "process_data.php". Every 4 odd seconds "process_data.php" echoes a flag which the outer ajax call needs to read and trigger another ajax call to a different script......your solution is using the ".done" method which waits for the ajax call to complete before making new ajax calls...

Comment: so `setTimeout` before ajax completes, do you think that?.. something like a throttle?